# I got an error while executing this script, is it correct script for off the vm instance in oracle cloud?

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

```
#/bin/sh
Stop - oci compute instance action  --action stop --instance-id  id-here
```

path: /var/

```
[root@vmscript etc]# ./stop.sh
./stop.sh: line 3: Stop: command not found
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].  Your question cannot be answered as it is.